# An alternative definition of a solvable group

Tags: galois-theory, solvable-groups

I'm putting together an outline for a paper on Galois theory. There are a few equivalent definitions of a solvable group, and I need to make sure that the one I'd like to use works, or more specifically, that the following is correct:

> Let $f$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $K$, and let $K'$ be the field obtained by adjoining the roots of $f$ to $K$. Then there is a sequence of sub-groups:
>   $$\text{Gal}(K'/K)=G_1\triangleright G_2\triangleright\ ...\ \triangleright G_n=1$$
>   **where for each $i$, $[G_i:G_{i+1}]$ is prime.**

Is this too strong a statement?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#Definition) states, "*for finite groups, an equivalent definition is that a solvable group is a group with a composition series all of whose factors are cyclic groups of prime order.*" However, this seems stronger than my statement, in which I don't require $(G_i)$ to be the composition series.

Comment: It is equivalent with being solvable in the finite case...

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, I saw something like that on the Wikipedia article for solvable groups, but I wasn't sure because it says "an equivalent definition is that a solvable group is a group with a composition series all of whose factors are cyclic groups of prime order", and my sequence $(G_i)$ isn't necessarily the composition series.

Comment: Whenever you saw that it probably mentioned "finite group*, otherwise infinite abelian groups wouldn't be solvable as they don't have composition series...

Comment: @DonAntonio I'll edit my question to include this.

Comment: Well @jack, no: not a problem, because a subnormal series with factors of prime order **is a composition series**, whether you require it or not...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $M\lhd G$ is superfluous: if $M\leqslant N\leqslant G$ then $[G:M]=[G:N][N:M]$ so either $N=M$ or $G=N$, i.e. $M$ is maximal.

Comment: Can we say that if $M\lhd N\lhd G$, then $[G:M]=[G:N][N:M]$, and so since $[G:M]$ is prime either $N=M$ or $N=G$?

Comment: @JackM Yes. Since you assumed $M$ was normal, I decided to give another proof, but as you note the condition that $[G:M]$ is prime suffices.